# How to configure Firebase during iOS XCUITest

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, xcode-ui-testing, fastlane

I'm looking to create a simple UI test that goes through an app's account creation, then checks against firestore to verify that the user's data is correct. So far, I have the UI driving done. The test drives the app through account creation and I can verify manually that the data is correct. My roadblock right now is being able to configure Firebase, Firestore, and Firebase Auth from the test file. I haven't been successful configuring it the way I do for the app itself (`FirebaseApp.configure()` pointing to a plist config file), the error being that it doesn't see a valid GoogleService-Info.plist file. Another related challenge is accessing auth from the test file, particularly getting the currently signed in uid so that I can locate the user's data in Firestone. Any ideas? Thanks

Also, for context, I want to create these integration tests to they are able to run as part of our CI/CD through a fastlane+github combo, although that'd not necessarily part of this question.

Answer (score 0):

To add Firebase to your iOS project, you must follow the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup):

I assume that you have already followed step 1 and 2 for creating a Firebase project and registering your app with Firebase.

## Step 3: Add a Firebase configuration file

1- Click Download GoogleService-Info.plist to obtain your Firebase iOS config file (GoogleService-Info.plist).

2- Move your config file into the root of your Xcode project. If prompted, select to add the config file to all targets.

## Step 4: Add Firebase SDKs to your app

1- We recommend using CocoaPods to install the Firebase libraries. Create a Podfile if you don't already have one:

```
cd your-project-directory

pod init
```

2- To your Podfile, add the Firebase pods that you want to use in your app.

```
# Add the pods for the Firebase products you want to use in your app
# For example, to use Firebase Authentication, Cloud Firestore, and Realtime 
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

3- Install the pods, then open your .xcworkspace file to see the project in Xcode:

```
pod install

open your-project.xcworkspace
```

## Step 5: Initialize Firebase in your app

1- Import the Firebase module in your UIApplicationDelegate:

```
import Firebase
```

2- Configure a FirebaseApp shared instance, typically in your app's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
// Use Firebase library to configure APIs
FirebaseApp.configure()
```